# Completeness of Taxi-Cab Metric in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ Under Certain Conditions

Tags: real-analysis

**Synopsis**

I need a hint in showing that the metric space $(Y,d)$ where $Y = \{\{a_j\}_{j=0}^{\infty} : \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|a_j| < \infty\}$ and $d(\{a_j\},\{b_j\}) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|a_j-b_j|$ is complete. Note that this is a lemma I'm using for a larger problem.

As for my attempts, I've decided to denote each sequence as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ since it makes the notation a bit more clear, with $p_i(\vec{x})$ being the $i$th projection of some vector $\vec{x}$. Take a Cauchy sequence $\{\vec{x}_k\}$ in $Y$. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $ N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall m,n \geq N$, we have $$|p_j(\vec{x_m})-p_j(\vec{x}_n)| \leq \sup(\{p_j(\vec{x}_m)-p_j(\vec{x_n})\}) \leq \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|p_j(\vec{x}_m) - p_j(\vec{x}_n)| = d(\vec{x}_m,\vec{x}_n) < \epsilon.$$ So each component is Cauchy and so converges component-wise to some sequence $\vec{l} \in \mathbb{R}^\infty$. I took a guess and said that this $\vec{l}$ was the limit of the Cauchy sequence under *this* metric. But I didn't know how to prove it. I tried making a sequence of $\epsilon_j = \frac{e}{\epsilon j!}$ with corresponding indices $N_j$ where for all $n \geq N_j$, we have $|p_j(\vec{x}_m) - p_j(\vec{l})| < \epsilon_j$ such that I could make maybe the following argument of: $$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|p_j(\vec{x}_m) - p_j(\vec{l})| \leq \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \epsilon_j = \frac{e}{\epsilon} \cdot e = \epsilon.$$ But then I realized that there were an infinite amount of indices then to choose from and that I can't say there's a specific index $N$ such that this inequality  holds true for all $n \geq N$. Then I tried finding some relationship between the Euclidean metric under which this limit exists due to the Component-wise convergence theorem and this sort of infinite taxi-cab metric, but I couldn't seem to come up with anything useful, since the Euclidean metric is less than or equal to the taxi-cab metric.

Perhaps I'm doing this all wrong. I know from a problem session with a TA that this space is complete, but I don't know how to show it.

For more information, I'm in a Real Analysis I course where the curriculum is a little unique. We go over integration and differentiation in Analysis II, but we go over sequences and series over metric spaces in the current course. We're allowed to use information like the convergence of Taylor series from Calc II, even if we haven't learned it rigorously yet. I hope that adds a bit of context.

Comment: This is just showing that $l_1$ is complete.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know this was a well known metric space. I'll search it up.

Comment: Good luck. The completeness argument is fairly standard.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel stupid now that I know how simple it is.

Comment: Don't. Most things are 'obvious' in retrospect.